# Bat - копирование с диска определённых файлов

Tags: bat

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста!
Необходимо в bat файле прописать код, который будет копировать файлы со всего диска D: с определённым расширением (*.txt, *.jpg и т. д.). Цель - одновременное копирование файлов нескольких расширений со всего диска, а не только с его корня. Была идея подбирать папки ("Фотографии", "Фото"), но решил откинуть эту идею по понятным причинам. Искал в интернете - не нашел ответ на вопрос. Заранее спасибо!)

Comment: смотреть оператор `for`, он позволяет обойти папки.

Comment: можно, пожалуйста, подробнее...

Comment: "рекурсивный обход папок" http://forum.oszone.net/thread-208291.html и вот http://scriptcoding.ru/2013/08/19/cmd-cykl/  остаётся только copy в цикл вписать, и защиту от "зацикливания"

Comment: Слышал, можно использовать `find` и, порекомендовали, `xcopy`. С `find` не знаю, как, а вот с `xcopy`, думаю, не получится. Он ведь больше для папок подходит, а не для копирования определённых файлов.

Comment: Также я собираюсь использовать один bat'ник, цель которого искать файлы с несколькими расширениями на диске d: (*.jpg, *.txt, *.doc...) и копировать всё в папку на съёмном носителе - `%~d0\files\d`. По идеи, он должен быть один, этот bat'ник...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну что-то типа

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT EXIST %1\. GOTO Usage
IF NOT EXIST %2\. GOTO Usage
FOR %%x IN (*.jpg, *.txt, *.doc) DO xcopy %1\%%x %2\*.* /S /Y /C
GOTO Done
:Usage
ECHO USAGE: %1 SourceFolder DestinationFolder
:Done
```

Это для начала. Можно захардкодить пути, или, наоборот, получать список имён/масок из параметров.

Comment: Я нашел код, который будет намного легче делать то, о чем я писал - `xcopy /S d:\*.doc %~d0\my\$127files\d` - ключ `/S` вероятно, преодолевает все папки

Comment: Абсолютно то же, что и у меня, вариант с хардкодом путей и маски. И не рекомендую пренебрегать ключами /Y и /C.